# Python CSV: is it possible to guess na_rep by reading some bytes?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, na

I'm trying to build a CSV parser able to work with just the CSV path as input.
At the moment I'm stuck at this code, where I'm able to guess the field separator 
and a few basic information.

```
import pandas as pandas
import csv


class CSVParser:
    path = None
    delimiter = None
    data_frame = None
    rows_count = None
    columns_count = None
    header = None

    def __init__(self, csv_path):
        self.path = csv_path
        self.delimiter = self.__guess_delimiter()
        self.data_frame = pandas.read_csv(self.path, delimiter=self.delimiter)
        self.rows_count, self.columns_count = self.data_frame.shape
        self.header = list(self.data_frame)

    def __guess_delimiter(self):
        with open(self.path) as csv_file:
            sniffer = csv.Sniffer()
            dialect = sniffer.sniff(csv_file.read(2048))
            delimiter = dialect.delimiter
        return delimiter.
```

I'm wondering if there is some easy way to be able to guess the na_rep of the CSV file by reading a few bytes.

Comment: in pandas' [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) the `na_values` section provides a list of items that get interpreted as `na`. A question of "Why do you want to know the "NA notation" of a file? might help us give you a better solution

Comment: This will be used as a sub-module of a graphic-interface to display info about CSV files.